# Using Lens to adjust user input in Monomer

Tags: haskell, haskell-lens

I'm writing a GUI app in [Monomer](https://github.com/fjvallarino/monomer) which has a [textField](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/monomer-1.5.0.0/docs/Monomer-Widgets-Singles-TextField.html#v:textField) function which accepts `ALens` which it uses to read/write input value into an `AppModel`    .

In my case `AppModel` looks like this:

```hs
data AppModel = AppModel
  { _activeComment :: Maybe Text
  }
  deriving (Eq, Show)
```

And so I'm using this lens:

```hs
textField (activeComment . non "")
```

I use `non ""` to get a default value, because `textField` requres a lens with `Text` focus.

Now I have these questions (I am only learning Lens):

1. Suppose I want to map user input and apply "h"-symbol to every key they type, how would I do that? I.e. I want to insert `(\t -> t <> "h")` mapping somewhere, but I can't figure out how. What is the operator I should use here? Is that from realm of `Iso`s? (didn't learn them yet)
2. What if I want to perform an effect on each key press, wait for the result and then set to to a lens focus? I guess this is not possible with current types. And this is probably more of a library question than a lens question, but still.

P.S. Here's an example of using `textField` from library samples in case docs are not enough: [example](https://github.com/fjvallarino/monomer/blob/main/examples/todo/Main.hs#L90)

Comment: I'm not sure about the library in general, but if you need an `Iso`, it feels like it shouldn't be hard to make.  Perhaps `withH = iso init (flip snoc 'h')`?